# Identify this chuck / faceplate mounting

Tags: tool-identification, lathe-chuck

I'm learning to turn, and found this in a box of chucks and faceplates. The central hole isn't threaded but is recessed on the inside, so I thought it might be a type of mounting for a faceplate, or for a worm screw. I don't know what its for, please can somebody tell me?

[image]

Comment: Some of the posts I've looked at in Google search results have suggested a faceplate without multiple holes was used by woodturners as a "sanding mount" (for sanding disks).  There are a number of older articles describing how one could turn their lathe into a decent and possibly variable speed disk sander. There were also cautionary notes about drilling your own additional holes in the plate to make it into the typical sort of faceplate we use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have s similar item which I have used as a one-screw faceplate.  Not a lot to say about it, just put a screw through the hole and into a small piece of wood to turn a small bowl.